# Mixed Media Queries for Desktop and iPad Landscape

Tags: ios, css, ipad, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm trying to set up a media query that will use the same stylesheet for desktop browsers with a viewport of 1024px or more, as well as iPads in landscape mode.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px)
```

For iPads in portrait mode, and phones, we have a different stylesheet that will load.

What's happening is that the desktop displays fine, but the iPad produces a blank page, because the desktop media query is not being recognized. However, the media queries for the portrait and phone versions aren't registering either.

I've tried various combinations, like
`@media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-height: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape), only screen  and (min-width: 1024px)` 
but nothing has worked.

What's the secret formula?

Thanks,

ty

Answer (score 0):

This appears to have done the trick:

```
@media only screen  and (min-width: 1024px),
@media only screen and (device-width: 768px) and (orientation: landscape)
```

Apparently, I was missing the `@media` for the second rule.

The problem now is that SASS won't render it. I get the following error:

```
Syntax error: Invalid CSS after "...width: 1024px),": expected media query (e.g. print, screen, print and screen), was "@media only scr..."
```